# What's the difference between double quotation marks and no double quotation marks for variables in a shell

Tags: bash, shell

```
 #! /bin/bash

set -x
sql="show tables;"

~/mysql/bin/mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -hxxxx -Pxxx -pxxx -uxxx -Drxxx $sql
~/mysql/bin/mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -hxxxx -Pxxx -pxxx -uxxx -Drxxx "$sql"
```

Results of enforcement:

[image: screenshot]

The execution with double quotation marks succeeded. Execution without double quotation marks failed.

What is the difference between `$sql` and `"$sql"`?

Comment: In brief, always quote unless you specifically require the shell to do token splitting and wildcard expansion on the value.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that:

```
./script foo bar
```

Gives a script 2 arguments, and

```
./script "foo bar"
```

Gives it 1 argument with a space in the middle.

If one works and the other doesn't for your MySQL command, it tells me that MySQL wants the SQL query to be specified as a single argument.

Comment: Why does the first command only cause tables

Comment: What do you mean 'cause tables'?